# Steps for Sign in mechanism with technology stack. AngularJS, API gateway, Cognito and Lambda

Tags: angularjs, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, api-gateway

I am working on Sign in mechanism with technology stack. AngularJS, API gateway, Cognito and Lambda. 
AngularJS Client ---> Api Gateway --> Lambda --> Cognito (behind lambda)

Note that : **i dont want to use cognito or Api gateway SDKs and i am using apiGatway  API calls over HTTP**.  I want to use sigv4 also. I have received the tokens (ID token,Access key and Session token.)in response of signin api call. I know i have to send the session token to my subsequent aPI call to provide authentication. But how? What are the steps involved in this process.?

Answer (score -1):

Angular -> API gateway is whatever custom stuff you want

You will need a custom sign-in service that returns a session key. You can either wrap Cognito calls and return whatever it gives you, or you can write some custom code to do things differently. Note that if you do use Cognito, the next step becomes easier.

If you make a custom session token, then API Gateway needs a [custom authorizer](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/use-custom-authorizer.html) to handle it. This is a lambda that will handle your authenticated requests and determine whether it's okay or not to continue.

If you go with Cognito session IDs, then you can [attach](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-integrate-with-cognito.html#apigateway-enable-cognito-user-pool) a cognito user pool as an authorizer to the API gateway, which is much easier.

And once you get that all working, your next steps will be handling session timeouts in Angular (plus a way to refresh a session via the backend, since you don't want to use Cognito SDK to do it automatically) and the rest of the user management process (creating a new login etc)

Comment: Thanks Trent Bartlem for your reply..i am advancing in my implementation step by step with understanding of how the authentication works.